# How to generate Aggregate graph in jmeter dashboard

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to generate Aggregate graph in jmeter dashboard as a custom graph in jmeter dashboard like we have an option in UI mode of jmeter. Basically I want to generate a graph with the average time of all my transactions. I know there is a section in jmeter dashboard about custom graphs and how to add it but I am not able to understand it how to use it in my case